# SIM900 module not responding on hardware COM port

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I've got my sim900 module working with arduino by using their software serial library, however, I want to eliminate arduino from the equation and have serial communication directly to sim900 module.

I'm using putty as my terminal emulator. It's serial is configured to `COM1 19200 8 N 1` the same as device manager configuration for this port.

I connect straight from hardware serial on my PCs motherboard into serial-to-ttl interface board which connects to sim900 module. The board has 4 pins - VCC GND TX RX. They're all connected to my sim900 hardware serial as follows: `VCC=5V GND=GND TX=TX RX=RX` (Yes I know that it's always actually TX=RX and RX=TX, but when I connect it that way my interface board doesn't blink any led to indicate a transfer whereas it does when I connect TX=TX and RX=RX). The switch on the module is set to hardware serial pins as well.

So the only thing that happens when I send AT commands such as `AT` or `ATI` and press enter is that puttys cursor comes back to the beginning of command that I typed. No response.

I'm thinking that I'm not doing something that the arduinos software serial port is doing when it sends commands to sim900.

Can anyone help please ? It's literally been days of trying different configurations with no results.

In that time besides getting sim900 working with arduino software serial I verified that the hardware serial port on my motherboard is working correctly and the interface board is working correctly as well.

Comment: Are you providing an external power source to the sim900?

Comment: Yes, the external power is there

Comment: Well, all I can suggest is to add an Arduino. Otherwise, why ask us?

Comment: What you mean "why ask us ?" I'm asking because I have a problem that I want to solve !

Comment: Yes, but you have removed the Arduino from the equation, so I fail to see how we, the *Arduino* Stack exchange, can help you with it?

Comment: There has been a similar question about connecting to the hardware serial pins on an Arduino Uno. The schematics revealed that this might be a problem. https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf

Comment: Why would that be a problem ? I've had my interface board connected to arduinos hardware serial on the breakout connector and running a sketch that just prints out "hello world". I've had the "hello world" printing correctly  on putty. However, I wasn't able to program arduino this way.

Comment: @Majenko - Although SIM900 can be used with many platforms, it is most commonly used with arduino, hence the reason I'm posting here.

Comment: But you aren't using it with arduino. You had no problems using it with arduino, so your problems must be related to things that we have no knowledge about.

Comment: Where do you suggest I go then ?